# XAML Islands ProgressRing White Background

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core

I'm porting a WPF app to WPF .NET Core 3.0.  I'm trying to use UWP controls using XAML Islands via WindowsXamlHost from the Community Toolkit. The WindowsXamlHost control itself has a white background and I don't know how to get rid of it. Here's an example of a ProgressRing:

```
<xamlHost:WindowsXamlHost x:Name="MyRing" InitialTypeName="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ProgressRing"/>
```

---

```
private void MyRing_ChildChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyRing.Child is ProgressRing progressRing)
    {
        progressRing.IsActive = true;
        var brush = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
        progressRing.Background = brush;
    }
}
```

Giving the ProgressRing object a new background color works but doesn't help if I'm after transparency. I'm using .NET Core 3 preview 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it is possible. I have a similar issue which I reported here: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/160#issuecomment-522288462. Hopefully, Microsoft employees will answer there.